# Understanding capacitors and developing intuition

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

I am trying to understand the property:

$$
i = C \cdot \frac{dV}{dt}
$$

and I'm tripping up over what the cause vs. effect is. When analyzing circuits, should I think about a capacitor responding to a change in its voltage by sourcing or sinking current, or should I think about the capacitor changing its voltage at a rate based on how much current goes through it? Or either of these depending on context?

For example, consider this full bridge rectifier with smoothing:

[image]

What is a better/more accurate way to think about this:

A. As the slope of the raw rectifier signal goes up (and therefore the capacitor's voltage as it's connected in parallel), the capacitor draws current away from the resistor, therefore lowering the voltage across the resistor. This smooths the signal.

B. As the raw signal starts going up, the capacitor provides a path for the current to go through, which creates a voltage across it as it charges. Once the raw signal is low, it releases current which lowers its voltage but at a shallower slope. This smooths the signal.

Comment: sometimes the water analogy could help ... think of the capacitor as a bucket of water ... the resistor is a small hole in the bottom ... the bridge rectifier is you adding water to the bucket, at regular intervals, using a coffee cup

Comment: @jsotola: the water analogy isn't perfect. 1) Part of the current supplied by the bridge does not enter the capacitor but goes directly to the load. 2) The coffee cup stream is more like a current source than a vlotage source which doesn't match the example:)

Comment: @Epix: You need to link to or cite the source of the image that you used . Copyright requires you to credit the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *should I think about a capacitor responding to a change in its voltage
> by sourcing or sinking current, or should I think about the capacitor
> changing its voltage at a rate based on how much current goes through
> it?*

A resistor is defined by \$i = \dfrac{1}{R}\cdot v\$

And, do we have problems here thinking about what happens? If a source is current then, we might write \$v = i\cdot R\$ and, if the source is voltage we might write the formula above. It's no different for a capacitor except we write \$\frac{dv}{dt}\$ instead of \$v\$.

> ***A.** As the slope of the raw rectifier signal goes up (and therefore the
> capacitor's voltage as it's connected in parallel),..*

Let me stop you and point out that the rectifier is reverse biased until the input voltage exceeds the capacitor voltage by a couple of diode drops. The impact of this is that current only passes into the capacitor at the peaks of the sinewave i.e. the capacitor is not connected in parallel with the voltage source for a good deal of the time. The current looks like this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simscape/ug/full-wave-bridge-rectifier.html).

> *... the capacitor draws current away from the resistor, therefore lowering
> the voltage across the resistor. This smooths the signal.*

That doesn't happen and I hope you can see that now.

> ***B.** As the raw signal starts going up, the capacitor provides a path
> for the current to go through, which creates a voltage across it as it
> charges. Once the raw signal is low, it releases current which lowers
> its voltage but at a shallower slope. This smooths the signal.*

And, I hope that you can see that this doesn't happen either.

> *What is a better/more accurate way to think about this*

You can think of the capacitor acting like an ideal battery; it gets recharged with a pulse of current when the input voltage magnitude is at a maximum and, for the rest of the time it is supplying current to the load trying to keep the voltage stable. The ripple you see is the charge-discharge process in action.

Comment: It is also important to realize that a capacitor also has considerable internal (series) resistance, which limits the current when a voltage is applied. The diodes and transformer also have resistance (and inductance) which also affect the charging (and discharging) current. There is also leakage (parallel resistance) that will "bleed off" the charge over a period of time, which can vary from less than a second to many days, so it is often recommended to add a "bleeder" resistor. Sometimes an LED can be added to warn of remaining charge.

Answer (score 3):

A capacitor can switch its behaviour in an instant. It can appear as a passive element with current entering its positive terminal, or, it can appear as a voltage source with current exiting the positive terminal.

During the interval when either D1 or D3 is conducting, the capacitor acts as a passive element. So the current through D1/D3 supplies both the capacitor and the load.

Here the capacitor is reacting to the rate of change in voltage resulting in a very large current pulse. So the changing voltage is the cause, and the capacitor current is the effect.
$$i_C=C\frac{dv_C}{dt}$$

During the time when D1 and D3 are not conducting, the capacitor acts as a voltage source. The current through a voltage source is defined by the load. How fast the voltage changes is determined by the current.

So the current is the cause, and the capacitor changing voltage is the effect.
$$\frac{dv_C}{dt}=\frac{i_C}{C}$$

The capacitor commutates between being a passive element while charging and a voltage source while discharging.

---

For an inductor, the same can be said by reversing the roles of current and voltage.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about it is that a capacitor 'tries to resist' to changes in voltage.

When the voltage of the source goes up quickly, the capacitor starts filling, so it 'forces' the voltage to go up slowly. And when the voltage of the source goes down quickly and the capacitor is full, it makes the voltage go down slowly by delivering its stored charge.

It acts like a buffer that needs some time to fill and some time to deliver its stored charge.
How 'slow' it charges and discharges, it depends on the capacity.

If the capacity is big enough and the frequency of the source wave is fast enough, the capacitor only has time to discharge a little before it goes up again,for each cycle. So the wave gets smoother.

But this is just an over-simplified vision of the process.

On the other side, an inductor 'resists' to changes in current.